# Which directory is secure to save the data

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I have made the application which has to download and store too many and may be infinite number of images time to time in the device. Now I am concerned about some points and that are given below

1. Downloaded Images should not be able to show in the Gallery
2. At the point of uninstall of app, the directory which contains my downloaded images should also get deleted.

For the sake of point no# 2 I have found the way to make the directory in such a way to get removed when the app is being uninstalled. Right now I am using the following two methods to save the data

**Procedure 1**

> File storagePath = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "MTest");

This is making the folder/directory with the name of "MTest"  in the following path **/data/data/com.example.demo.myapplication/filesMTest/S_12~ipad.png**

Or

**Procedure 2**

> File storagePath = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir("Mtest")+"");

This is making the folder/directory with the name of "MTest"  in the following path **/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.example.demo.myapplication/files/SMU/Mtest/S_6~ipad.png.png**

and they both folder gets deleted when the app is uninstalled from the device and also the images in them are not able to show in the gallery.

**But If I use the following Procedure 3**

> File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "MTest");

its makes the folder in external storage I guess so , and the folder remain in the device even we have uninstall the app , and also it can be able to show in the device gallery.

**What I want**

I am not sure that If I use the procedure 1 and 2, then

1. Is it the secure way to download in these folder path.
2. Can I able to store as many images and unlimited space in the device?
3. If I use the procedure 3 How am I able to remove the folder when the app is being uninstalled?
4. I want My app  in such a way that its created folder which is used to save the data should get deleted when app is being uninstalled also it should have as much space available as much the app requires .

Please suggest me the way which is able to do all that things ? or tell me which way is best either procedure 1, 2 OR procedure 3 . According to the behavior of app which I discussed above in the end.

Comment: You forgot nr 4. Using an app specific directory on a removable micro-SD card. As with all other solutions you have 'unlimited space' until the card is full.

Comment: @greenapps I do not want to use the sd card as some people do not use that sd card with their devices

Comment: You should give the user the possibility to choose between 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: no man  I am not talking in that context , lets discuss , what would have happen , if user select option 1 and pictures start downloading into the app installation directory , ? would there any storage limit like 100mb max or anything ?

Comment: 'into the app installation directory'. No. getFilesDir() delivers private internal memory. Of course there is a limit to internal memory. And mostly there is less internal memory then external memory. There are not to much devices which have 32 GB external memory like a micro-SD card easily provides. 100mb ? Do you mean 100 MB?

Comment: i just wanted to know that , i want to save pictures , even if the pictures took , upto 1 gb  but it should not crash the app ,

Comment: I read it some where that 'into the app installation directory' there is a limit of data , near about 100 mb